# Fetch data from PostgreSQL using django-pgviews

Tags: django, postgresql

I used django-pgviews in my Django project and I want to get data from **django-pgviews** but It shows an error that,

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation

But views which created using **django-pgviews** are exist in database and I can retrieve data in pgadmin. But I can't use those views in front end.

[image: Error message]

[image: created view]

[image: Pgadmin]

Answer (score 0):

Not found a good solution for this problem, then finally we decided to create model and view( with SQL query) separately and it worked. Because I wanted to create view in PostgreSQL when I do a migration to my project.

[image]